# Report a column values corresponding to 1st non-zero and last zero values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below. I would like to scan through 'Krg' column and find the row that corresponds to the last zero value in this column and to report 'Sg' from this row (0.03). Additionally, I would like to report 'Sg' corresponding to 1st non-zero value of 'Krg' (0.04).

I could achieve that using query() - see my code below.

```py
import pandas as pd

col_labels = ['Sg', 'Krg', 'Krw', 'Pc']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_labels)

f = open('EPS.INC', 'r')
for line in f:
    if 'SGWFN' in line:
        print('Reading relative permeability table')
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if (line.split() and not line.startswith('/') and not line.startswith('--')):
                cols = line.split()
                df=df.append(pd.Series(([float(i) for i in cols]), index=col_labels), ignore_index=True)



print(df.loc[df.query('Krg != 0')['Krg'].idxmin(), 'Sg'])
print(df.loc[(df.query('Krg != 0')['Krg'].idxmin())-1, 'Sg'])
```

```
      Sg       Krg       Krw         Pc
0   0.00  0.000000  1.000000   0.000000
1   0.03  0.000000  0.500000   0.091233
2   0.04  0.000518  0.484212   0.093203
3   0.05  0.001624  0.468759   0.095237
4   0.06  0.003171  0.453639   0.097338
5   0.07  0.005098  0.438848   0.099508
6   0.08  0.007367  0.424382   0.101751
7   0.09  0.009953  0.410237   0.104070
8   0.10  0.012835  0.396410   0.106469
9   0.11  0.015999  0.382897   0.108950
10  0.12  0.019431  0.369695   0.111518
```

The code does not seem to be too "pandorable" and appears to be slow. Is there a smarter way of obtain those 'Sg' values?

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simplify this by using [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) which stand for `equal` and `not equal`. We combine [`DataFrame.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) and [`DataFrame.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) to get he first and last row.

---

```
m = df['Krg'].ne(0)
n = df['Krg'].eq(0)

df.loc[m, 'Sg'].head(1).iloc[0]
df.loc[n, 'Sg'].tail(1).iloc[0]
```

Output

```
0.04
0.03
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first situation, we make sure 'Krg' is 0, and that the value after 0 in the 'Krg' column is not 0.

```
df.loc[(df['Krg'] == 0.00000)&(df['Krg'] != df['Krg'].shift(-1)), 'Sg']
```

For the second situation, we use a similar thought process to the above one, but make sure that the row above is 0 instead, and that they both arent 0.

```
df.loc[(df['Krg'].shift(1) == 0.00000)&(df['Krg'] != df['Krg'].shift(1)), 'Sg']
```

Using %%timeit, my version is about 35% faster.

Comment: Thanks for that. The only issue is that the original output seems to be a value whereas your suggestion outputs either a dataframe or a list. Is there a way to report them as values only?
```
1    0.03
Name: Sg, dtype: float64
2    0.04
Name: Sg, dtype: float64
```

Comment: you can add ```.values``` and you will just get the single value as a np array.

Answer (score 0):

I am just using idxmax and try to speed up your original post

```
s=df.query('Krg != 0')['Krg'].idxmin()# here you only need run idxmax once not twice 
print(df.loc[s, 'Sg'])
print(df.loc[s-1, 'Sg'])
```